# Obtener el estado de una preferencia (Checkout básico) MercadoPago SDK PHP

Tags: php, api, mercadopago

Buenas tardes a todos estimados, me encuentro implementando un chekout básico de mercadopago en nuestro sistema **Centro de Pago**.

Nuestro **Centro de Pago** es el lugar donde nuestros clientes registran sus pagos realizados a traves de la banca en linea, pero en esta ocasion queremos integrar tambien los pagos online con MercadoPago.

Antes de enviar el pago, en nuestro sistema almacenamos y creamos la preferencia de pago con los datos del cliente y los que necesitamos, adicionalmente asociamos el parametro **external_reference** una variante del ID de transaccion de la preferencia que estamos enviando a mercadopago (para una validacion posterior al pago). Tambien tengo el parametro **auto_return** = all.

Los pagos se devuelven a nuestro portal solo si el pago es "aprobado", los pagos en cualquier otro estado se mantienen en la web de MercadoPago. No logro hacer que MercadoPago me informe a traves del IPN (pues no se configurarlo) del "status" de estos pagos.

Busque una alternativa de poder consultar el estado de un pago, pero al parecer me devuelve un json vacío; Mi pregunta es: **¿como puedo obtener el # de cobro de una preferencia?**, presento mi codigo:

```
/* Creo la preferencia */
$datosjson = array(...);
$herramientaPago = $objMercadoPago->create_preference($datosjson);
$transaccion = substr(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $herramientaPago["response"]["id"]),-12);
$datosjson["external_reference"] = $transaccion;
$herramientaPago = $objMercadoPago->update_preference($herramientaPago["response"]["id"],$datosjson);
```

Luego de esto almaceno los datos escensiales en nuestra base de datos y envíamos al usuario a MercadoPago para que realice su pago.

Si el pago es concretado sin problemas, todo funciona de maravilla. Pero si por alguna razon, el usuario cierra la ventana de mercadopago, o cancela o es negado o existe alguna otra razon distinta, ese estatus nunca llega a nuestros servidores, y por lo tanto, el pago (previamente almacenado) queda en stand-by...

He intentado buscar un pago especifico a traves del external_refererence, pero no lo he logrado:

```
$transaccion = substr(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $_POST["transaccion"]),-12);
$objMercadoPago = new MP(...);
$filtros = array (
            "external_reference"=>$transaccion
        );
$datosjson = $objMercadoPago->search_payment ($filtros);
```

Este array esta simplemente vacío, pero considero que es porque no logra ubicar el # de cobro de la preferencia, quisiera saber como puedo obtenerlo.

**Nota**: Al ingresar a traves del portal web de MercadoPago, veo el pago alli (haya sido negado o no) y tambien veo el # de cobro, si utilizo ese # de cobro con el mismo codigo de busqueda, el array devuelto esta con todos los datos como deberia estar.

Answer (score 2):

He solucionado mi propio dilema :)...

Ubique en la documentacion de MercadoPago el **Payments Search API** donde te permite ubicar el pago de la siguiente manera:

Anteriormente  lo tenía de esta manera:

```
$transaccion = substr(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $_POST["transaccion"]),-12);
$objMercadoPago = new MP(...);
$filtros = array (
        "external_reference"=>$transaccion
    );
$datosjson = $objMercadoPago->search_payment ($filters);
```

Lo he solucionado asi:

```
/* Esto es mi external_reference */
$transaccion = substr(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $_POST["transaccion"]),-12);
$objMercadoPago = new MP(...);
$datosjson = $objMercadoPago -> get("/v1/payments/search?external_reference={$transaccion}");
```

De esta manera obtengo los datos que necesito y puedo actualizar lo que necesito.

Answer (score 0):

A ver si me puedes ayudar. 
Yo tengo hecha la integración con PHP...Funciona todo ok como lo tuyo...si es success, retorna en 5 segundos y capturo todo.
Pero no logro hacer funcionar lo de las notificaciones para recibir el status y actualizar la base de datos, enviar el pedido, etc. en caso de que no vuelvan al sitio del vendedor.

Podrías ayudarme con eso?

Tengo mi código:

payment.php

```
require_once "mercadopago/lib/mercadopago.php";

// Credeciales de MP
$mp = new MP("", "");

$total_a_pagar = 150;

$claveCompraMp = rand(0000,9999);
$claveCompraMp = rand(000,999).rand(0000,9999);

$preference_data = array(
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "title" => "Hipcam",
            "currency_id" => "ARS",
            "category_id" => "Camaras",
            "quantity" => 1,
            "unit_price" => 1 * $total_a_pagar
        )
    ),
    "back_urls" => array(
        "success" => "http://localhost/MIWEB/success",
        "failure" => "http://localhost/MIWEB/fail",
        "pending" => "http://localhost/MIWEB/pending"
    ),
    "auto_return" => "approved",
    "notification_url" => "https://www.hipcam.com/es/notificacionesmp2",
    "external_reference" => $claveCompraMp,
    "expires" => false
);

$preference = $mp->create_preference($preference_data);
```

Abajo tengo mi botón para crear la preferencia...

Pero lo que me falta es justamente esa página PHP que llame a ver que está pasando...y como activar bien las IPN estaba leyendo.

Gracias!
Daniel.